# Check if a function is a cdf

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am studying cumulative density functions. As an exercise, given a cdf $F$ I am trying to say if functions built on $F$ are also cdf. I would like to check a few answers to understand if my reasoning is correct:

$G(x)=F(bx)$ for some $b<0$ I argued it is not a cdf since $lim_{x\to +\infty} F(bx) = lim_{x\to -\infty}F(x) =0$ but we know that for a cdf $lim_{x\to +\infty}F(x)=1$.

Along the same lines I also said that $G(x)=F(x^2)$ is not a cdf, while $G(x)=F(at), a>0, G(x)=F(x+c), G(x)=F(x^3), G(x)=F(x)^2, G(x)=F(x)^3$ are cdf.

Other functions I checked are $G(x)=1/2(1+tanh(x))$ which seems to be a cdf to me.
I have huge problems (I think because of my lack of knowledge in calculus) with the following two:
$G(x)=lim_{a\to +\infty} 1/2(1+tanh(ax))$
$G(x)=lim_{a\to 0^+} 1/2(1+tanh(ax))$

How do I calculate $lim_{x\to +\infty}(lim_{a\to +\infty} 1/2(1+tanh(ax)))$ and the other properties as well?

Thanks

Comment: Use the definition of tangens hyperbolicus in terms of exponential functions:

$\text{tanh} (x) := \frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$

Comment: I tried, but still, when I try to understand what the function does when x goes to infinity I have issues, it's like a double limit, but I am not sure how to calculate it... Initially I thought that being the limit a number, it was like $lim_{x\to +\infty} (1) = 1$ when $a \to +\infty$ and  $lim_{x\to +\infty} (1) = 1/2$ when $a\to 0^+$ but is it correct?

Comment: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1-1/e^{2x}}{1+1/e^{2x}} = \frac{1-0}{1+0} = 1$.

Does this help?

Comment: So: $lim_{x \to \infty} (lim_{a \to \infty} 1/2 (1+tanh(ax)))= lim_{x\to \infty}(1)=1$ and $lim_{x \to \infty}(\lim_{a \to 0^+ }1/2(1+tanh(ax))= 0$ ??  Also,$lim_{x \to -\infty} (lim_{a \to \infty} 1/2 (1+tanh(ax)))=1$ ?Thanks a lot for your hints!